# Covert List to Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the list

```
[[(1, 1, {(58091,)}, ('roma',))], [(11, 11, {(97042,)}, ('lecco',))], [(3, 3, {(97068,)}, ('pescate',))]]
```

I would like to save data in 4 columns as following

```
id one   id two   id       place
1           1     58091     roma
11         11     97042     lecco
3           3     97068     pescate
```

what I did

```
your_list = [[(1, 1, {(58091,)}, ('roma',))], [(11, 11, {(97042,)}, ('lecco',))], [(3, 3, {(97068,)}, ('pescate',))]]
df = DataFrame (your_list,columns=['id one','id two','id','place'])
```

but it is not working I believe it is due to the brackets but I do not know how to deal with them

Comment: From what I have seen, your list looks incomplete to me: ```{(58091,)}, ('roma',))```, why are there extra ```,``` when there is no other value?

Comment: I'd suggest to ensure your input data (`your_list`) is of proper format before turning it into a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: @Sujay That's a tuple with one element.

Comment: any hint how to clean the data input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this particular data format, you can flatten the list of lists using a custom function with list comprehension:

```
data = [[(1, 1, {(58091,)}, ('roma',))], [(11, 11, {(97042,)}, ('lecco',))], [(3, 3, {(97068,)}, ('pescate',))]]

def unnest(s):
    if isinstance(s, str) or isinstance(s, int):
        return s
    else:
        for i in s:
            return unnest(i)

print (pd.DataFrame([[unnest(z) for z in y] for x in data for y in x],
                    columns=['id one','id two','id','place']))

   id one  id two     id    place
0       1       1  58091     roma
1      11      11  97042    lecco
2       3       3  97068  pescate
```